# After updateing Android Studio from 2.3 to 3.0, getting lot of ANR in my app

Tags: android, multithreading, mutex, deadlock, android-anr-dialog

I have my app on Play store. It was working smoothly. I updated android studio to 3.0.  I was having one bug for Android 8.0 and fixed it and given update to beta, On play console Suddenly I am getting lot of ANR for beta version.
ANR LOG:
Main Thread:

```
"main" tid=1 Native
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x7705e0c0 self=0x7faecc7a00
  | sysTid=10892 nice=0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x7fb387ba98
  | state=S schedstat=( 75891624606 69036517474 324114 ) utm=5953 stm=1636 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7ffa823000-0x7ffa825000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000001c2ac  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #01  pc 00000000000e925c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+156)
  #02  pc 00000000005a0f4c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL12GoToRunnableEPNS_6ThreadE+328)
  #03  pc 00000000005a0dc0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art12JniMethodEndEjPNS_6ThreadE+28)
  #04  pc 000000000098dd70  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_os_BinderProxy_transactNative__ILandroid_os_Parcel_2Landroid_os_Parcel_2I+220)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (Native method)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact (Binder.java:628)
  at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getActivityInfo (IPackageManager.java:3154)
  at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getActivityInfo (ApplicationPackageManager.java:498)
  at android.app.TaskStackBuilder.addParentStack (TaskStackBuilder.java:172)
  at android.app.TaskStackBuilder.addParentStack (TaskStackBuilder.java:152)
  at com.techdev.internetspeedmeter.Services.ChargingFullService.a (unavailable)
  at com.techdev.internetspeedmeter.Services.ChargingFullService.run (unavailable)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke! (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)`
```

Heap Task Demon: Blocked Thread

```
"HeapTaskDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 Blocked
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x2ac06310 self=0x7fa96b5800
  | sysTid=28555 nice=0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x7fa87fe450
  | state=S schedstat=( 1624332930 212501030 609 ) utm=153 stm=9 core=4 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fa86fc000-0x7fa86fe000 stackSize=1037KB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000001c0b0  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+32)
  #01  pc 00000000000e7374  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable9TimedWaitEPNS_6ThreadEli+176)
  #02  pc 000000000023f3c4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc13TaskProcessor7GetTaskEPNS_6ThreadE+296)
  #03  pc 000000000023fce0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc13TaskProcessor11RunAllTasksEPNS_6ThreadE+92)
  #04  pc 00000000001e4ff0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (Java_dalvik_system_VMRuntime_runHeapTasks__+124)
  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks (Native method)
- waiting to lock an unknown object
  at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.run (Daemons.java:433)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:761)
```

**By checking ANR trace, Main thread is getting blocked, but it would have come earlier also of this update, why it is coming after upgrading studio 2.3 to 3.0**
Specially it is coming for android marshmallow and above.

For all threads, please find image below.

[image]

Note :- You can find the entire crash log at this link :-
https://pastebin.com/ZbqQETFs